# Ubuntu 22.10 no Dolby Digital passthrough pavucontrol

Tags: sound, pavucontrol, 22.10, pipewire, ac3

In ubuntu 22.04 I was able to determine with PulseAudio Volume Control which audio signals such as DD (AC3), DD+ (EAC3) and DTS were sent to my receiver via HDMI.

The audio of the videos that I played with VLC 3.0.17.4 was sent to my receiver in the correct format.

Since 22.10 with Pipewire as audio server that no longer works, my receiver no longer switches between DD, DD+ and DTS signals (defaults to DD). For example, when I play DTS audio, my receiver stays on DD.

In PulseAudio Volume Control I can still set which signals my receiver understands, but after a reboot these options are all turned off again. So the settings are not saved.

When I set the audio signals back in PulseAudio Volume Control after a reboot, DTS is passed on to my receiver but AC3 and EAC3 often not or I hear intermittently very stuttering audio, as if a piece of audio is repeated over and over like a sample.

I've reinstalled PulseAudio Volume Control, Wireplumber and Piperwire but that didn't help.

Are there others who have this problem?

Tips to play AC3/EAC3 in a different way are also welcome!

[image: all advanced audio options turned off again after reboot]

^ all advanced audio options turned off again after reboot

Next I tried setting the formats manually via terminal. First I got the ID of the sink with

```
pactl list short sinks
```

I got the id and I did

```
pactl set-sink-formats 56 'pcm;ac3-iec61937;eac3-iec61937;mpeg-iec61937;dts-iec61937;mpeg2-aac-iec61937'
```

I checked with **pactl list sinks** if formats were there, they were. However I got the same result with audio, with DTS being sent to my receiver and AC3 / EAC3 not playing. After reboot I checked with **pactl list sinks** again and then the only format listed was PCM, the rest was gone again.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on?

Also - is it normal that the sink ID changes? Yesterday the HDMI sink ID was 56, today it is 52.

I got my info from the Migrate PulseAudio wiki at Pipewire [Gitlab](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Migrate-PulseAudio).